# Convert char Array/string to bool Array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, boolean

We have this field in our database indicating a true/false flag for each day of the week that looks like this : '1111110'

I need to convert this value to an array of booleans.

For that I have written the following code :

```
char[] freqs = weekdayFrequency.ToCharArray();
bool[] weekdaysEnabled = new bool[]{
    Convert.ToBoolean(int.Parse(freqs[0].ToString())), 
    Convert.ToBoolean(int.Parse(freqs[1].ToString())),
    Convert.ToBoolean(int.Parse(freqs[2].ToString())),
    Convert.ToBoolean(int.Parse(freqs[3].ToString())),
    Convert.ToBoolean(int.Parse(freqs[4].ToString())),
    Convert.ToBoolean(int.Parse(freqs[5].ToString())),
    Convert.ToBoolean(int.Parse(freqs[6].ToString()))
};
```

And I find this way too clunky because of the many conversions.

**What would be the ideal/cleanest way to convert this fixed length string into an Array of bool ??**

I know you could write this in a for-loop but the amount of days in a week will never change and therefore I think this is the more performant way to go.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A bit of LINQ can make this a pretty trivial task:

```
var weekdaysEnabled = weekdayFrequency.Select(chr => chr == '1').ToArray();
```

Note that `string` already implements `IEnumerable<char>`, so you can use the LINQ methods on it directly.

Comment: The test should be `chr == '1'` as you are comparing characters.

Comment: Thats what I love about stackoverflow, you ask a question and a minute later you have ur answer ;D you have to change the double quotes in to single quotes though cuz we're dealing with chars but otherwise this compiles ok :D Thanks!

Comment: @Darin: Feel free to just edit the post next time, when it's clearly a typo. ;)

Comment: @Peter: No prob, glad it does the job.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET 2

```
bool[] weekdaysEnabled1 =
Array.ConvertAll<char, bool>(
    freqs,
    new Converter<char, bool>(delegate(char c) { return Convert.ToBoolean(int.Parse(freqs[0].ToString())); }));
```

Comment: weekdaysEnabled1 is wrong : 'allWeekdays' is right

It's just a more concise syntax, but I think the number of conversion is the same :( I don't know why the public static bool ToBoolean(char value) method is not implemented in the framework